How to simulate click after extracting data using Playwright
I'm trying to simulate a next page using Playwright but I have to gather data first. The data per page only returns 50 posts. I need to get the first 150 post. The first 50 I can get data but on the next post I'm having a hard time because of the for loop because it's not async.
This is my approach:
  const browser = await chromium.launch({headless: false});
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();


  await page.goto("localhost:3000/posts");
  
  // This data only returns the first 50 posts
  const data = await page
    .getByRole("table")
    .nth(2)
    .locator("tbody")
    .locator(".age")
    .all();

  const strings = [];

  for (const row of data) {
    strings.push(await row.innerText());
    console.log(await row.innerText());
  }

  await page.locator(".morelink").click({clickCount: 2, delay: 5}); <-- after click I wanted to run the `const data = await page...` code again 2 times to get the first 150.

  console.log(strings);

I'm not familiar with Playwright so I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to chain locator and simulate click.

The comment says hacker news, but the actual URL is localhost:3000/posts, which I don't have access to. Can you share the actual site and expected output? Thanks. Generally, paginate the goto with a traditional for loop or for .. of loop.

hacker news was the sample post until i fixed some issue on the backend. but im reading the local backend now.

for some reason i lost the answer but I was building on that. I just missed some methods on the documentation and I was reading the HTML wrong. its not a child its a neighbor node.
